# How to handle a game-loop with vue + vuex (or any other state-management framework)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, redux, vuex

I'm currently building an idle-game using Vue 2.x with vuex.

The game is text-based which means there are no graphic and makes all game features easy to integrate with vue. My game features are all tied to vuex, I don't have external code that I inject into vue: vuex handle everything.

I came across a problem, where my game-loop which calculate delta time and the number of times to *update* the game, if there was any frame lose. Since my game-logic is tied to vuex, I need to dispatch like 20 to 60 actions/seconds (depending of the FPS) with vuex to update some parts of my game (a time in seconds that increment until it reaches a certain value).

I'm worried to see my vuex dev-tools spammed by the `scriptLoop` (which makes it useless) and that it will probably impact game performance.

I don't know if it's the proper way to do it, if I'm missing something or if simply state-management frameworks were not done for this (which I think).

Here some parts of the code I'm talking about:

```
// App.vue: core component
public loop(): void {
  this.now = new Date().getTime();

  const elapsed = this.now - this.before;
  const times = Math.floor(elapsed / this.interval);

  (elapsed > this.interval) ? this.update(times) : this.update(1);

  this.before = new Date().getTime();
}

// Update some parts of the game-logic by dispatching the SCRIPT_LOOP action
public update(times: number): void {
  this.$store.dispatch('SCRIPT_LOOP', times);
}

// scripts.mutations.ts: SCRIPT_LOOP action commit this mutation
...
scriptLoop(state: ScriptsState, payload: { scripts: string[], times: number }) {
  payload.scripts.forEach((script) => {
    (state.scripts.find((scr) => scr.name === script) as Models.Script).progression += times / 30;
  });
},
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fix for this was to create an external (not vuex-related) game-logic, where in the class initializer I pass my vuex store, so my external game-logic can react on store state changes and even dispatch/commit if needed.